# Extract location from a string with a city, state, country in it?

Tags: nlp

How could I extract a location from a string like `San Francisco 49ers` and get San Francisco from it? The only way I can is by training a neural-network, but training with every city, state, country, location is expensive isn't it? Wouldn't it be?

Is there another way to approach this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about choosing the software library, not about the NLP algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the string with a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).  You can use the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to enter a location like `San Francisco` and get data related to that location, like latitude, longitude, etc.

Yes, building your own geolocation service would be very costly - let Google's API do the work for you!

Comment: I forgot that I am already using the geocoding api! Thank you. I'll see if it works!